# Bootstrap modal window behind other page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having some difficulties after deploying a locally developed site to a live server. My modal windows are appearing behind other page content on the live server (they work fine on the local version).

I've tried modifying the `z-index` values and positioning, but neither seems to have an effect.

[Here's one of the pages in question](http://www.floradesigninc.com/products/rolls/?&SingleProduct=715)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the modal outside of your list. The modal's z-index isn't working properly when it is nested like that. I usually put my modals at the bottom of my html, right before I load in any scripts.

Comment: I wish I could, but it's inside a page generated by a catalog plugin. (The modal window is for displaying available sizes). So there's no way for me to change it's placement in the html.